# Group theoretic interpretation of the cohomology of $K(G, n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a discrete group. Let $H^n(G; \mathbb{Z})$ be the group cohomology of $G$ (with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$). Then it's a well-known theorem that $H^n(G; \mathbb{Z})$  is isomorphic to the singular cohomology of the Eilenberg-MacLane $K(G, 1)$

One consequence of this theorem is that the cohomology groups of a $K(G, 1)$ have a purely group-theoretic definition and interpretation.  In particular, you can compute the cohomology of $K(G,1)$ simply from information about the group $G.$

My question: do the cohomology groups of $K(G, n)$ for $n>1$ also admit a purely group theoretic definition and/or interpretation?

Comment: This is complicated but classical. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24754/cohomology-of-the-eilenberg-maclane-spaces-kg-n for references.